# Bootstrap footer input group not stretching to fit page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I've added a footer onto a chat app i'm trying to make with socketio.

The issue I've got is that the markdown input group is not stretching to the page.

If i take out `position: fixed;` from the "footerr" class then it stretches to fit, but is no longer at the bottom of the page.

Ideally the footer will not go over the sidebar, will auto responsivly resize, aligned to the right and fit the whole "main" section of the page.

Can anyone help?

https://jsfiddle.net/fxyhgz7t/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Catamaran:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c551403873.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"
            integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../static/css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<div class="d-flex mainpage" id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar-heading font-weight-bolder text-center ">Basic Chat App</div>
        <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar">Dashboard</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar">Shortcuts</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar">Overview</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar">Events</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar">Profile</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar">Status</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light topbar border-bottom">
            <div class="row justify-content-between w-100">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <button class="btn togglebutton" id="menu-toggle">Rooms</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="text-right h2">Main Room</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!--Messages ----->
        <div class="container-fluid mainpage">
            <div class="row mx-1 my-2 align-top">
                <div class="col-md-auto text-left">
                    Lewis
                </div>
                <div class="col-md text-left">
                    <div class="row justify-content-start">
                        <div class="col-md-auto bg-warning text-right ml-2 py-1 message_local">
                            Test message from me
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row  mx-1 my-2 align-top">
                <div class="col-md-auto text-right order-12">
                    Someone Else
                </div>
                <div class="col-md text-right order-5">
                    <div class="row justify-content-end">
                        <div class="col-md-auto text-right mr-2 py-1 message_remote">
                            Test message from another person
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <footer class="footerr">

            <div class="input-group mx-2 my-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username"
                       aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </footer>
    </div>  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- Footer -->


<!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
<script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is `.footerr` a typo?

Comment: No it's not. I was testing different opinions and this was one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `width: 100%;` to .footerr

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar (https://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar)
 * Copyright 2013-2020 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */
.togglebutton{
  color:#FAFAFF;
  background-color: #B0B5B3;
}
.sidebar{
  background-color: #353B3C!important;
  color: #C6C7C4;
}
.topbar{
  background-color: #22577A!important;
  color: #EEF0F2;
}
.mainpage{
  background-color: #EEF0F2!important;
}

.message_remote{
  border-top-left-radius: 10px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px !important;
  background-color: #A2999E!important;
}
.message_local{
  border-top-left-radius: 10px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px !important;
  background-color: #22577A!important;
  color:#FAFAFF;
}


.tooltip {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #666;
    text-align:left;
}

.tooltip h3 {margin:12px 0;}

.tooltip .right {
    min-width:200px;
    max-width:400px;
    top:50%;
    left:100%;
    margin-left:20px;
    transform:translate(0, -50%);
    padding:0;
    color:#EEEEEE;
    background-color:#444444;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:13px;
    border-radius:8px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99999999;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    box-shadow:0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    visibility:hidden; opacity:0; transition:opacity 0.8s;
}

.tooltip:hover .right {
    visibility:visible; opacity:1;
}

.tooltip .right img {
    width:400px;
    border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;
}
.tooltip .text-content {
    padding:10px 20px;
}

.tooltip .right i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -12px;
  width: 12px;
}


html, body {
  font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
}
 #wrapper {
    overflow-x: hidden;
 }
#sticky-footer {
  flex-shrink: none;
}

.footerr {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -15rem;
  -webkit-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  transition: margin .25s ease-out;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
  padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
  width: 15rem;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  min-width: 100vw;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  #page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -15rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Catamaran:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c551403873.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"
            integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../static/css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<div class="d-flex mainpage" id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar-heading font-weight-bolder text-center ">Basic Chat App</div>
        <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar">Dashboard</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar">Shortcuts</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar">Overview</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar">Events</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar">Profile</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action sidebar">Status</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light topbar border-bottom">
            <div class="row justify-content-between w-100">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <button class="btn togglebutton" id="menu-toggle">Rooms</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="text-right h2">Main Room</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!--Messages ----->
        <div class="container-fluid mainpage">
            <div class="row mx-1 my-2 align-top">
                <div class="col-md-auto text-left">
                    Lewis
                </div>
                <div class="col-md text-left">
                    <div class="row justify-content-start">
                        <div class="col-md-auto bg-warning text-right ml-2 py-1 message_local">
                            Test message from me
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row  mx-1 my-2 align-top">
                <div class="col-md-auto text-right order-12">
                    Someone Else
                </div>
                <div class="col-md text-right order-5">
                    <div class="row justify-content-end">
                        <div class="col-md-auto text-right mr-2 py-1 message_remote">
                            Test message from another person
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <footer class="footerr">

            <div class="input-group mx-2 my-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username"
                       aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </footer>
    </div>  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- Footer -->


<!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
<script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jaocampoo's answer should work. A better solution would be adding a container-fluid class to the footer, while maintaining the .footerr class.